# anything like add_meta_box for categories?

Tags: plugin-development, categories, custom-field

I want to add few custom fields to categories. So I am looking for something like `add_meta_box` but for categories.

Is there any **WP function** like that for **categories**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add content to the [category edit pages](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/edit-tag-form.php) by hooking into the `edit_category_form_fields` (still in the form table) or `edit_category_form` (outside the table but before the submit button). Similar hooks exist for tags or custom taxonomies, check the source. To handle these extra values you need to find a good hook yourself, make sure you handle it [before `editedtag` redirects you](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/edit-tags.php#L135).

There are no clean meta box handlers, you need to write most code yourself. But please let us know how you did it, it might be interesting for others!

Comment: maybe do_meta_boxes is helpful with this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_meta_boxes

Answer (score 1):

it's pretty alpha... but this was supposed to be a branch off of the awesome WP_Alchemy which kicks butt at regular metaboxes

https://github.com/farinspace/wpalchemy/tree/taxonomy

Answer (score -1):

this hook works only for original WP categories. Is there any solution/hook how to add custom form fields to custom category (taxonomy) type? Thanx

Comment: Indeed, in the source you can see that `edit_tag_form_fields` fires for everything that is not a category, and `[taxonomy name]_edit_form_fields` then again for all taxonomies (so `people_edit_form_fields` for a `people` taxonomy, but also `category_edit_form_fields` again for a category). And I know you can't comment yet, but once you can, you should do that instead of adding a new "answer" to ask a clarification. Otherwise it might get ignored.