# Choosing different templates for categories

Tags: categories, themes, templates

I was searching about changing the default template of the categories in WordPress, I saw the codex which says that the only way by making a new file with the slug or the ID of the category, like this `Category-ID.php` or `Category-SLUG.php`

But I want to know if there's a way to add a dropdown menu with different templates when making new categories, just like pages..

Is it even possible? If so, how?

Comment: Yes it is possible. It should not be done this way(responding/ansswering as I do now) but here is a link for a ["how to"](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/easily-apply-templates-to-your-wordpress-category-pages/) Maybe using google is next time also an option before asking?

Comment: @Charles It's really old plugin, didn't even work!

Comment: Maybe looking [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51228/15605) for the answer, [his](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-category-template/) plugin works like a charm! WP 4.2.2

Comment: @Charles Please consider adding it as an answer to mark the question as resolved

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom template in the theme and give options for each category to select the template.

The custom fields for a category can be added using, 'Advanced Custom fields' plugin or you can refer [this](https://pippinsplugins.com/adding-custom-meta-fields-to-taxonomies/) article.

Once you do this, you need to edit the 'category.php' file, to set the template for the category. You will have to use the custom field value to select and load the corresponding template. You can use, 'get_template_part()' function for this.